# How to restrict the user to download data from amazon S3 usin IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

- I have many buckets and none of them should allow anonymous access
- The user I have added must have access to one bucket only and should
  be able to enter any other bucket
- The user must NOT be able to  add/modify/delete buckets
- The user should be able to list files in  his bucket
- The user must NOT be able to download files from the buckets The user
  should be able to add files in the bucket

please suggest

Comment: Basically you can manage the access using policies. So you can restrict / allow operations over the buckets. A policy (set of rules) may be assigned to a role (I'd prefer that one) or/and to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your requirements are:

- You have multiple IAM Users
- Each user will have their own bucket
- Users can list the contents of their bucket and upload files to their bucket
- Users cannot do anything else to the objects in their bucket, nor to the bucket itself

To do this, you will want to create a policy for each **IAM User**.

The policy would look something like:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::Ahito-Bucket"
      }
   ]
}
```

See: [User Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)

An alternative method is to **have all users share one bucket**, but create a policy that **limits users to their own directory**.

See: [IAM Policy Elements: Variables - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)